# server.servletPath=/* not working in spring-boot.version 2.1.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

I have been using the below property in the `application.properties` file with `spring-boot.version 1.5.6.RELEASE` without any issues.

```
server.servletPath=/*
```

This was a workaround to enable a method in a library class which uses the function `getPathInfo()` of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` to get a valid value instead of `null`.

I had to go with this workaround since there is no support of that library jar anymore.

This workaround started failing when I upgraded my application to `spring-boot.version 2.1.7.RELEASE`

`server.servletPath` is changed to `spring.mvc.servletPath` from Spring Boot 2 onwards.

I tried setting the below property and it did not work

```
spring.mvc.servletPath=/*
```

I also tried the below function in my configuration class and it did not work.

```
@Bean
    public DispatcherServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration(
            DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet,
            ObjectProvider<MultipartConfigElement> multipartConfig) {
        DispatcherServletRegistrationBean registration = new DispatcherServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet, "/*");
        registration.setName("dispatcherServlet");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(-1);
        multipartConfig.ifAvailable(registration::setMultipartConfig);
        return registration;
    }
```

Could you please provide a working solution for this property using `spring-boot.version 2.1.7.RELEASE`?

Thanks,
Dhinu

Answer (score 2):

The correct setting for newer spring versions is:

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/some/path
```

This changes the mapping of the DispatcherServlet, so all resources served by spring are mapped to this path.

If you set:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/some/path
```

The whole web context is changed.

The main difference is that setting the dispatcher servlet path allows you to register additional servlets on other paths while with context path set, spring boot's tomcat can only serve content below that context path.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following config property on latest spring boot version:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/*
```